# Slow Ubuntu desktop 14.04

Tags: unity, gnome

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 but the Desktop appears to be really laggy...ie opening the unity menu or dragging windows etc...

I installed the classic desktop using these instructions: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-classic-gnome-flashback-session which was better but I do actually like Unity and would like to use it if possible.

The machine I am running is a Lenovo ThinkCentre M55.

- Intel® Core 2 Duo Processor E6400
- Integrated Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 3000
- 3GB RAM

I'm guessing my machine isn't up to it but I thought I would ask if there are any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be a graphics driver / opengl issue. I am using Gnome for my Ubuntu 14.04, I just don't like the Unity interface. Both the Unity interface and the Gnome compiz interface where very slow and laggy until I installed the proprietary Nvidia driver (and stopped using Neuvou). Do you have the latest Intel driver installed ?

Also, I think Unity uses compiz doesn't it ? Install 'compizconfig-settings-manager' and play with the composite and opengl settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Intel Graphics Driver? That might help:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/intel-linux-graphics-driver-installer-1-0-5

Comment: Yeah I did try this - didn't help.

Comment: Try testing your hardware like HDD and so on to make sure they are not at fault. If everything comes back okay then I guess you would have to try a lighter desktop environment.

Comment: Just popped the XFCE version of linux mint on there and its absolutely fine, but will test the hardware anyways.

Comment: Also, check to make sure you have done all the updates possible for Unity before completely disregarding it.

Perhaps your systems is just not up to running heavy desktop environments.